# Change the image size and range

Tags: pytorch, transform, normalization, image-resizing

I want to ask for data transforms if I have an image of size 28 * 28 and I want to resize it to be 32 *32, I know that this could be done with `transforms.Resize()` but I'm sure how.

Also for the normalization, if I want it to be within the range of [-1,1], I did it previously if I want it to be within [0,1] using `transforms.Normalize((0.485,0.456,0.406),(0.229,0.224,0.225))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rage, it's gonna be fine. Resizing `MNIST` to `32x32` `height x width` can be done like so:

```
import tempfile

import torchvision

dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root=tempfile.gettempdir(),
    download=True,
    train=True,
    # Simply put the size you want in Resize (can be tuple for height, width)
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose(
        [torchvision.transforms.Resize(32), torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()]
    ),
)

print(dataset[0][0].shape) # 1, 32, 32 (channels, width, height)
```

When it comes to normalization, you can see PyTorch's per-channel normalization source [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L192). It depends whether you want it per-channel or in another form, but something along those lines should work (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) for formula of the normalization, here it's applied per-channel):

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Normalize:
    maximum: typing.Tuple
    minimum: typing.Tuple
    low: int = -1
    high: int = 1

    def __call__(self, tensor):
        maximum = torch.as_tensor(self.maximum, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
        minimum = torch.as_tensor(self.minimum, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
        return self.low + (
            (tensor - minimum[:, None, None]) * (self.high - self.low)
        ) / (maximum[:, None, None] - minimum[:, None, None])
```

You would have to provide `Tuple` of minimum values and `Tuple` of maximum values (one value per channel for both) just like for standard PyTorch's `torchvision` normalization though. You could calculate those from data, for MNIST you could calculate them like this:

```
def per_channel_op(data, op=torch.max):
    per_sample, _ = op(data, axis=0)
    per_width, _ = op(per_sample, axis=1)
    per_height, _ = op(per_width, axis=1)
    return per_height

# Unsqueeze to add superficial channel for MNIST
# Divide cause they are uint8 type by default
data = dataset.data.unsqueeze(1).float() / 255

# Maximum over samples
maximum = per_channel_op(data) # value per channel, here
minimum = per_channel_op(data, op=torch.min) # only one value cause MNIST
```

And finally, to apply normalization on MNIST (watch out, as those will only have `-1`, `1` values as all pixels are black and white, will act differently on datasets like CIFAR etc.):

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root=tempfile.gettempdir(),
    download=True,
    train=True,
    # Simply put the size you want in Resize (can be tuple for height, width)
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose(
        [
            torchvision.transforms.Resize(32),
            torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
            # Apply with Lambda your custom transformation
            torchvision.transforms.Lambda(Normalize((maximum,), (minimum,))),
        ]
    ),
)
```

Comment: Hahaha :), that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

**[`Resize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize)**
This transformation gets the desired output shape as an argument for the constructor:

```py
transform.Resize((32, 32))
```

**[`Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize)**
Since `Normalize` transformation work like `out <- (in - mu)/sig`, you have `mu` and `sug` values that project `out` to range [-1, 1]. In order to project to [0,1] you need to multiply by 0.5 and add 0.5. You can play around with the equations and see that the new mean you need to provide is `old_mean - old_sig`, and the new sigma is `2 * old_sigma`.
In your case:

```py
transforms.Normalize((0.256, 0.232, 0.181),(0.458, 0.448, 0.45))
```

if you want to normalize a single channel in range [0,1] to range [-1,1] you need to subtract .5 and divide by 0.5:

```
transform.Normalize((.5),(.5))
```

Comment: For the normalization, this is for 3 channels; what if I want it for 1 channel, i.e transforms.Normalize((X,),(Y,)) with the same condition that the values range between [-1,1]